# Why can't I get embedded Python to work in a C++ / MFC application with Python functions longer than one line?

Tags: python, c++, mfc

I am trying to embed Python 3.4 in a C++ / MFC / Windows application.

I am trying to use PyRun_SimpleString to import a Python module, so something like:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import testmod")
```

is what I have.  Here is testmod.py:

```
def hello():
    return 5;

def four(input):
    print(input * 4);
```

When I import this (via PyRun_SimpleString), PyRunSimpleString returns 0 (good), when I change testmod.py to:

```
def hello():
    c = 5
    return c;

def four(input):
    print(input * 4);
```

I get a return value of -1...something went wrong.  I also hit a breakpoint which I put in

```
static void print_error_text(PyObject *f, int offset, PyObject *text_obj)
```

which is in pythonrun.c

Okay, this one seems pretty strange to me.  Any ideas?

Comment: have to ask: are you mixing tabs and spaces? and does this import into a python console?

Comment: why do use have semicolons in your Python code?